# App is available for my device, but I can't install it?

Tags: google-play-store

How should I understand the following situation:

[image]

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.greenway.evcharge&hl=en&gl=US

> This app **is available** for *some of your devices*

An app is available, but I can't install it because Install button is disabled.

Comment: It is saying that the app is compatible for *some* of your devices (not the device you are trying to install to). You have multiple devices and it's installable on some of them. This is in line with recent [Compatibility for your active devices’ section](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.xda-developers.com/play-store-compatibility-active-devices-section/amp/)

Comment: Try removing `&gl=US` just in case it's geoblocked.

Comment: @beeshyams I have read the last section and it behaves the same thing to me. The `gl` parameter locks the geolocation of the Play Store listing and it may affect the app availability. [This was with `&gl=US`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfJ8j.png) and [this was without `&gl=US`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOBVM.png) when accessing from Indonesia with Nexus 5 and Pixel 3a in the device list.

Comment: @beeshyams Your first comment seems invalid, because the screenshot is captured on my PC. I virtually never install anything from a mobile device, because I find it much more handy to open corresponding app's screen on my PC. Bigger screen, better usability (mouse + keyboard) and the ability to install single app on many devices using just a single PC. So the "Install" button should be enabled on that PC for at least one of the _some_ devices, if I am getting this correctly. Thank you for all your time and try to help.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for trying to help. This turned out to be one-time glitch so I think that we should close this question (as off-topic / can't reproduce?). I restarted browser, then the whole PC, I have cleaned my cookies, all for nothing. Button stayed inactive. About five minutes later, when I was considering creating a blank new browser account, it simply started to work again and I finally was able to install that app. Thank you again.

Comment: Instead of closing it, makes sense to describe you were trying to install from PC and it got fixed by itself. May help someone else in similar situation//cleaned up my comments

Comment: Well crickey I had the same problem. Removing the &gl=US from the url fixed it it for me. Thanks @AndrewT.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Google Play for web / PC / Edge / Windows 11.

When you analyse a source code of the *Install* button, you can see the following:

[image]

For some weird reason (a bug?) Google Play adds the following:

```
 data-disable-idom="true" disabled=""
```

to the `<button>`'s code.

Removing this fragment and closing Dev Tools allows user to click *Install* button and continue.

Nothing unusual happens next. User goes through the regular: *Verify, it is you* + password + device pick + *App will be soon installed* path and naturally app is installed in about next 3-5 minutes.

Comment: I had the same when I **searched for apps compatible with my watch**. When I performed this trick, It only allowed me to install it on some(!) of my devices but not my watch!

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Maybe unrelated. Is your app supported to work on your watch?